# SeleniumRC with Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I wrote some junit test cases using seleniumrc . I am trying to integrate the test cases with Jenkins.
I installed seleniumrc-plugin for eclipse.I am unable to add the test cases to jenkins. 
In `Jenkins--> COnfigureProject --> Build Environment --> Create Seleniumrc instance` ,I entered all the details for

```
Host , Port ,Browser ,OS
```

After that,I don't know what to choose for Build. I tried going through this source

```
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SeleniumRC+Plugin
```

but couldnt figure out a way. Can anyone please explain me in detailed what to do next?

Comment: Selenium WebDriver is the successor of Selenium Remote Control which has been officially deprecated

Comment: I dont want to use WebDriver because I have to change a lot of code. So I want to continue using SeleniumRC.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure Selenium manager and Remote Agents according to pt. 1 and 2.
After that on Jenkins CI configure Host and Port which must point to machine where "Selenium manager instance" is launched (it can be the same or another machine)